# Optimizing the fitting of Ordinary Differential Equation(NDsolve) involving interpolation functions

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, fitting, interpolation, data

I am a newbie to this forum.  I am trying to use NDsolve to solve some ODEs involving the interpolation function.  Then, I will compare the fitted curve and data to determine the ODE coefficients.

Basically, I measure the Voltage(V) and Current(I) for a circuit. Then I want to use these V and I to determine the value of electric components in the circuit.

First, I make a interpolation function out of the waveform V data:

```
dataIndex = Range[2, 10001];
myVoltData = Transpose[{rawData[[dataIndex, 1]], rawData[[dataIndex, 4]]}];
myCurrData = Transpose[{rawData[[dataIndex, 1]], rawData[[dataIndex, 2]]}];
voltageFunc = Interpolation[myVoltData, InterpolationOrder -> 2];
```

Second, use `NDSolve` to solve the ODE, then use the solution to calculate the chi-sq. In the following code, the ODE parameters to be fit are `r0Fit, r1Fit, c1Fit, currOffset`, and the function `fitFunc` will eventually return the chi-sq:

```
fitFunc[r0Fit_?NumberQ, r1Fit_?NumberQ, c1Fit_?NumberQ, currOffsetFit_?NumberQ] :=  
Block[ {sol, curr00, curr11},  
sol = NDSolve[ {voltageFunc[t] == curr00[t]*r0Fit + curr11[t]*r1Fit , 
         curr00[t] == (curr11[t] + r1Fit*c1Fit/10^6*curr11'[t]), 
         curr00[t0fit] == curr11[t0fit] == (voltageFunc[t0fit])/(r0Fit + r1Fit)},
         {curr00, curr11}, {t, t0fit, t1fit}, AccuracyGoal -> 7][[1]];    
Apply[Plus, 
((myCurrData[[fitDataRange, 2]] + 50*currOffsetFit/10^6 
- 50*Flatten[curr00[t] /. sol /.t -> myCurrData[[fitDataRange, 1]]])
/myCurrDataErr[[fitDataRange, 2]])^2/dataPnts]     
]
```

Finally, use `NMinimize` find the fitting result with chi-sq minimum:

```
Timing[fitResult = NMinimize[ {fitFunc[r0f, r1f, c1f,  iOffset],
 130 < r0f < 170, 3000 < r1f < 3200, 650 < c1f < 750, 60 < iOffset < 100}, 
 {r0f, r1f, c1f,  iOffset},AccuracyGoal -> 0, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]]
```

My first problem is, since `voltageFunc[t]` is the interpolation function from data, it severely procrastinates the `NDSolve` command, as a result, the `NMinimize` is consuming vast amount of time(>20 mins).    I wonder, why does interpolation function of ODE delay `NDSolve` so much? Is there any optimization method to make the `NMinimize` and `NDSolve` faster?

Secondly, `NMinimize` occasionally fails to find the global minimum. Any suggestions to improve the fitting result's reliability.

Any suggestion is appreciated.    Thank you all.

Comment: Hey, anyone interested in this problem. Just a update, I finally solved the problem in IGOR, which has a better solution for fitting ODE.

Answer (score 1):

You can try solving the differential equation once and for all with

```
solCurr =  DSolve[{voltageFunc[t] == curr00[t]*r0Fit + curr11[t]*r1Fit, 
   curr00[t] == (curr11[t] + r1Fit*c1Fit/10^6*curr11'[t]), 
   curr00[t0fit] == curr11[t0fit] == (voltageFunc[t0fit])/(r0Fit + r1Fit)}, 
  {curr00, curr11}, {t}]
```

which will involve integrals over your `voltageFunc`. This should improve speed at least.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this idea. It seems to use DSolve to replace NDSolve. However, I tried it in my notebook and it fails to execute， probably due to that DSolve has difficulty to handle interpolation function.

Comment: My suggestion is to use `DSolve` only once leaving `voltageFunc` unspecified. The next step is to substitute your `voltageFunc` into the general solution and then feed this to `NMinimize`.

Comment: I just tried to use the solution from DSolve.   But it take even longer time to do the integral for interpolation function.   It seems that the interpolation function is always pain for numerical analysis.   I probably will switch to matlab or IGor by manually solving the ODE via Runge-Kutta method.

Comment: Could you post a sample of your data so I can have a try ?

Comment: Hi Firstly, thank you very much for your attention on my problem.       Secondly, I feel myself stupid enough being not able to find any file upload button here.    Can you leave me you email addr so that I can send data file and my NB file.    Thanks

Comment: You can use websites such as [imgur](http://imgur.com) so that the files will be available to everyone else.

Comment: Hi,   I have uploaded my files (data file and NB file) [here](https://sites.google.com/site/bouldershgresearch/home/mathematica-files) .    The uploaded NB file has a slightly more complicated ODE, but the basic idea is still identical.